# Mixing Numbers and Symbols as Footnote Markers in Minipage

Tags: symbols, environments, footnotes, minipage, renewcommand

I am writing a document using LaTeX, and I would like to have number and symbol markers for the footnotes of a single page. For instance, I would like to have a superscript "1" and follow it with "*" and "2"; such that, each of those markers will refer to a different reference in the footnote.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            test text \footnotemark,\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnotmark[1]\\
        \end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

You can clearly notice that I am having my footnotes inside a minipage environment. In addition, `\footnotemark` will insert superscript "1". Then by the `\renewcommand{...}{...}` I will be able to change the numbers to markers, but I am not able to insert the reference text by using `\footnotetext{}`. Can someone help me with that?

I hope my explanation was clear enough.

Comment: Footnotes are implemented using TeX `\insert` and it works only outside boxes. It must be in the main vertical list (or in paragraph mode: the `\insert`s are moved to the main vertical list when paragraph is built). Try to move the `\fotnotetext` after the box, it means just after the minipage environment.

Comment: @wipet minipage supports footnotes that are placed at the end of the minipage box